# Modification of my image when doing a mosaic

Tags: python, mosaic, image-mosaic

I'm trying to assemble a bunch of images with the mosaic method but I got some transformation in my images.

Here's the code I use in Python :

```
import os
import datetime
import rasterio
from rasterio.merge import merge
from rasterio.transform import from_origin
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
from rasterio.warp import reproject, Resampling as Resamp

# Path to the folder containing TIFF files
tif_folder = r"C:\Users\aurel\OneDrive\Documents\Mémoire\Datasets\Landsat_aquatic\extraction"

# Create a dictionary to store files by date and band
files_by_date_and_band = {}

# Iterate through all files in the folder
for file_name in os.listdir(tif_folder):
    full_path = os.path.join(tif_folder, file_name)

    # Check if the file is a TIFF file with one of the specified bands
    if file_name.endswith('.tif') and any(band in file_name for band in ['BAND1', 'BAND2', 'BAND3']):
        # Extract the date and band from the file name
        date_str = file_name.split('_')[3]
        band_str = file_name.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y%m%d').date()

        # Add the file to the dictionary under the date and band key
        key = (date, band_str)
        if key in files_by_date_and_band:
            files_by_date_and_band[key].append(full_path)
        else:
            files_by_date_and_band[key] = [full_path]

# Iterate through the dictionary and perform merging for each date and band
for (date, band), files in files_by_date_and_band.items():
    # Read each band separately with rasterio
    bands = [rasterio.open(file) for file in files]

    # Ensure consistent spatial grid (reprojection)
    mosaics, out_transform = merge(bands, resampling=Resampling.nearest)

    # Save the multiband mosaic to a new file with reprojection
    output_mosaic = f'C:/Users/aurel/OneDrive/Documents/Mémoire/Datasets/Landsat_aquatic/mosaique/{date}_{band}.tif'
    with rasterio.open(output_mosaic, 'w', driver='GTiff', 
                       height=mosaics.shape[1], width=mosaics.shape[2], 
                       count=mosaics.shape[0], dtype=mosaics.dtype, 
                       crs=bands[0].crs, transform=out_transform) as dest:
        dest.write(mosaics)

    # Close rasterio sources
    for band in bands:
        band.close()

print("Multiband mosaics generated successfully.")
```

And here are the results I got :

Initial images to assemble
[image]
The result :
[image]
Comparaison of the two :
[image]

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the images did not have the same projection (35N while the other was in 36N). I found the solution to his here [How to mosaic images with different CRS with rasterio](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311837/how-to-mosaic-images-with-different-crs-with-rasterio)